# Can functions be defined within a shebang executable GNU Octave file?

Tags: function, octave

Given an Octave m file heading with `#! /usr/bin/octave -q`, can a function be defined inside this file?, or the only way to do it is to invoke functions defined in another file?

Comment: Have you tried and see what happens?

Comment: Actually I did, and it would had been nice that I report on it, but the result was so weird that I preferred not to add confusion to the statement. (Well, the solution resulted to be as weird as the original behavior :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can. The only thing is that the first Octave statement must not be a function definition which is why many Octave programs will start with `1;`. However, my experience is that most Octave programs need a package so the first statements can be just the loading of said packages.

Here's an example Octave program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env octave
## Do not forget your license

pkg load foo;
pkg load bar;

1; # not really necessary because of the pkg load statements above

function foobar ()
  ## this function does something amazing
endfunction

function main (argv)
  disp (argv);
endfunction

main (argv ());
```